# i cannot get my javascript number-sorter to work

Tags: javascript

i am making a number sorter that alerts the number of different numbers (e.g. 11223 would be returned as number of ones = 2, number of twos = 2, number of threes = 1 ect. ect.)

here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea width="100" height="50" id="text" onBlur="sort();"></textarea>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
var no1 = 0
var no2 = 0
var no3 = 0
var no4 = 0
var no5 = 0
var no6 = 0
var no7 = 0
var no8 = 0
var no9 = 0
var no0 = 0
var other = 0
var split = text.split("");
function sort() {
    for (i = 1; i < split; i++) {
        if (string[i]===1) {
            no1++;
            return no1;
        }
        else if (string[i]===2) {
            no2++;
            return no2;
        }
        else if (string[i]===3) {
            no3++;
            return no3;
        }
        else if (string[i]===4) {
            no4++;
            return no4;
        }
        else if (string[i]===5) {
            no5++;
            return no5;
        }
        else if (string[i]===6) {
            no6++;
            return no6;
        }
        else if (string[i]===7) {
            no7++;
            return no7;
        }
        else if (string[i]===8) {
            no8++;
            return no8;
        }
        else if (string[i]===9) {
            no9++;
            return no9;
        }
        else if (string[i]===0) {
            no0++;
            return no0;
        }
        else {
            other++;
            return other;
        }
    }
    alert("number of ones = " + no1 + ", number of twos = " + no2 + ", number of threes = " + no3 + ", number of fours = " + no4 + ", number of fives = " + no5 + ", number of sixes = " + no6 + ", number of sevens = " + no7 + ", number of eights = " + no8 + ", number of nines = " + no9 + ", number of zeros = " + no0 + ", number of other characters = " + other + ".");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i enter a value and click away from the text field it returns 0 for all the variables

please help

Comment: Tons of errors. For example, `i = 1`, should be `var i = 0`. Javascript arrays are 0-based. Then `i < split` should be `i < split.length`. You don't want to compare a number and an array. And of course `return` will stop the loop on the very first iteration...

Comment: still returning zero's

Comment: how do i continue the loop with the return

Comment: @The_HTML_Man your first statements are incorrect , rest seems fine

Comment: I think you should learn some basic things about js before trying to do something with it. Here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/m08wewvq/ but you'd better try something on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not very easy to maintain, so I made my own version, try it out:

```
function sort() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    // will contain a list of chars with their associated count
    var charCounter = {};
    for (var i = 0, l=text.length; i < l; i++) {
        var char = text[i];
        // if char is a number
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(char))){
            if(charCounter[char]){ charCounter[char]++; }
            else { charCounter[char] = 1; }
        // if char is not a number
        } else {
            if(charCounter['other characters']){ charCounter['other characters']++; }
            else { charCounter['other characters'] = 1; }
        }
    }
    outputList(charCounter);
}

function outputList(obj){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var output = '';
    for(var i=0, l=keys.length; i<l; i++){
        output += 'Number of ' + keys[i] + ' : ' + obj[keys[i]] + '.\n';
    }
    alert(output);
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to use an array of words for the number names and use it for keys on an object that accumulates the count of occurrences of each digit, e.g.

```
function countDigits(n) {

  // Array of number names
  var words = ['zeros','ones','twos','threes','fours',
               'fives','sixes','sevens','eights','nines'];

  // Split number into digits
  var nums = String(n).split('');
  var counts = {};

  // Count how many of each digit
  nums.forEach(function(n){
    if (!(counts.hasOwnProperty(words[n]))) counts[words[n]] = 0;
    ++counts[words[n]];
  });

  // Write to output
  words.forEach(function(w){
    console.log('Number of ' + w + ' = ' + (counts[w] || 0) + '\n');
  });
}

countDigits(1012023405);

/*
  Number of zeros = 3
  Number of ones = 2
  Number of twos = 2
  Number of threes = 1
  Number of fours = 1
  Number of fives = 1
  Number of sixes = 0
  Number of sevens = 0
  Number of eights = 0
  Number of nines = 0
*/
```

Or a slightly different formulation:

```
function countDigits(n) {

  // Array of number names
  var words = ['zeros','ones','twos','threes','fours',
               'fives','sixes','sevens','eights','nines'];
  var counts = [];

  // Split number into digits and count
  String(n).split('').forEach(function(n) {
    counts[n] = counts[n]? counts[n] + 1 : 1;
  });

  // Write to output
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    console.log('Number of ' + words[i] + ' = ' + (counts[i] || 0) + '\n');
  }
}
```